# How do I prevent the Arc effect to be undone after I ungroup the objects I used it on?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I grouped a bunch of little things together and arced it, and it looked fine. I later tried to modify a single one of my objects and it didn't work without modifying everything, so I ungrouped them.
After I ungrouped everything, the arc disappeared.
How do I make this not happen?

I can rasterize it and it'll become one object, but I don't want that.

I tried using flatten transparency and the outlines actually go on the arced object now, which is cool, but I can't modify one individual object without modifying the whole thing.

Comment: You need to describe the processes in much more detail. "I arced it" doesn't explain HOW you did that. And how would make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm somewhat guessing here....

Your "arc" effect was most likely applied by choosing the menu item `Effect > Warp > Arc...` This applies, as the menu eludes to, and **effect** on the selected object. What this means is that it alters how the object appears not how the object is constructed. Effects are "live" in order to allow further editing or refinement at a later time.

If you applied the effect to a group, when you ungroup, the effect is thrown out.

If you want to "bake in" the effect, you can choose `Object > Expand Appearance` from the menu before ungrouping. Or, another alternative is to use `Object > Envelope Distort > Make With Warp`. The Envelope is sort of in between expanded art and live art. Which one works best would depend upon the actual artwork.